# Returning new redux state with edited object properties

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, redux

When a user adds the same product to cart, instead of creating a new object with the same properties in the state, I'm trying to increment the object property `quantity` of the same product in the state. Since state shouldn't be mutated directly, I'm creating a copy of the state, editing the `quantity`, then returning the new array. But I'm getting `"Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"`. Is this the proper "redux" way of doing this? Below is my add to cart case in root reducer.

```
export function rootReducer(state, action): IAppState {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_PRODUCT:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            products: state.products.concat( Object.assign({}, action.payload) )
        });
    case REMOVE_PRODUCT:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            products: state.products.filter(t => t.id !== action.payload)
        });
    case REMOVE_ALL_PRODUCTS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            products: []
        });
    case ADD_TO_CART:
        let duplicateItem = state.cartProducts.filter(item => item.id === action.payload.id);
        let duplicateIndex;
        if(duplicateItem.length) {
            for(var i = 0; i <= state.cartProducts.length - 1; i++){
                if(state.cartProducts[i].id === duplicateItem[0].id){
                    duplicateIndex = i;   
                }
            }
            let newArray = {...state.cartProducts};
            newArray[duplicateIndex].quantity = newArray[duplicateIndex].quantity === undefined ? 1 : newArray[duplicateIndex].quantity++;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                cartProducts: newArray
            });
        }
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            cartProducts: state.cartProducts.concat( Object.assign({}, action.payload.product ) )
        });
    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            cartProducts: state.cartProducts.filter(t => t.id !== action.payload)
        });
    case CLEAR_CART:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
           cartProducts: [] 
        });
  }
  return state;
}
```

Below are the interfaces

```
export interface IProduct {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: string;
  category: string;
  quantity?: number;
}
export interface IAppState {
  products: IProduct[];
  cartProducts: IProduct[];
}
```

Comment: Safal you may get many answers but the best advice anyone can give is there is no need to "copy" the array and then edit it this is the only information you need to succeed.

All possible array transformations can be performed immutably ONLY using Array.prototype.reduce

All possible object transformations can be performed immutably using ONLY Object.assign

Comment: Also please provide a before and after of the state and i can give you the transformation can't read through without knowing more

Comment: @ShanonJackson Updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking to modify the cartProducts with the new quantity.
A simple loop through the cartproducts will do the trick.

`case ADD_TO_CART :
     return Object.assign({}, state, {
         cartProducts: state.cartProducts.map((item, index) => (item.id === action.payload.id) 
             ? item.quantity++ : item.quantity = 1)
})`

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you are using the `spread operator` it's only creating new ref for the first level. The second level, however, is pointing the same references.
eg,

```
    let collection = [
      { 
        someData: 1
      }
    ]

    let secondCollection = collection.map(item =>
      item.someData = 2
    )

console.log(collection) //[{someData: 2}]
console.log(secondCollection) //[{someData: 2}]
```

In this case you have to also copy the second level. With Spread operator, eg,

```
let secondCollection = collection.map(item => {
  let newItem = {
    ...item
  }

  newItem.someData: 2
  return newItem
})

console.log(collection) //[{someData: 1}]
console.log(secondCollection) //[{someData: 2}]
```

This can be frustrating and there are many ways to get away with less difficulties. `Normalization` is one good way. Here is a reference for redux states:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

If you are comfortable using third party libraries there is `cloneDeep` method in `lodash` which will do the copying of deep levels for you:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep

For your updating cart:

It can be simplified a lot. There is absolutely no need to take the duplicate item in an array and `for` looping through it and beyond.

Let's try to simplify it:

```
//assuming the carProducts state as
[
  {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 2,
  }
]

let newState = carProducts.map(item => {
  let newItem = {...item} //or _.cloneDeep(item)

  newItem.quantity = item.quantity + 1 //or add up the payload

  return newItem

})
```

You should also separate products, carProducts etc. states in a different reducer for simplicity and more control.

Please feel free to comment if you have something unclear :)